# Deploying Flutter Web App To Hostgator/normal FTP means?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have been really interested in Flutter for the last few months and have been following the beta Flutter for web information. I was wondering, other than the ones mentioned in the documentation (Firebase, Github, Google Cloud), is there a way to currently test my app via using my Hostgator hosting and use something like Filezilla to publish the application/site?

I understand this is in a beta state. I only ask because the documentation states that there is a way to publish via those services but doesn't mention the way I am asking. I also understand that this is not production-ready.

Thank you all for any help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just run:

`flutter build web`

And then copy the contents of build/web to your web host's document root via a panel or FTP or something else.

Comment: It's crazy how simple that was and yet I could not find that information anywhere. Thank you!